# Search post based tag in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I has two table, post and post_tag. Structure of the two tables is like this :

```
--Post--
id|Content|user_id

--Post_tag
id|post_id|tag( type = var char / tag name)
```

I use query like this :

```
post::whereHas('post_tag', function ($query) use ($tags) {
                    $query->where('tag', $tags);
                });
```

I want to get all post based tags (ex : tags php and its return all post that have tag php ) but it returned error undefined whereHas method , is any reference should I read? Thanks in advance

Comment: a post has many tags?

Comment: Yep, one post has many tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add relationships to your models

```
//Post

public function tags()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Post_tag::class);
}


// Post_tag

public function posts()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
}
```

then you can get all posts based on a tag like

`$posts = Post_tag::with('posts')->where('tag','php')->get();`

Comment: Ah i forgot to add relation in post_tag model , thanks. It worked now